# Get max key in dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
MyCount= {u'10': 1, u'1': 2, u'3': 2, u'2': 2, u'5': 2, u'4': 2, u'7': 2, u'6': 2, u'9': 2, u'8': 2}
```

I need highest key which is 10 but i if try `max(MyCount.keys())`  it gives 9 as highest. 

Same for `max(MyCount)`.

The dictionary is created dynamically.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This is because `u'9' > u'10'`, since they are *strings*.

To compare numerically, use `int` as a key.

```
max(MyCount, key=int)
```

(Calling `.keys()` is usually unnecessary)

Comment: Calling `dict.keys` is usually superfluous.

Answer (score 20):

You need to compare the actual numerical values. Currently you're comparing the strings lexigraphically.

```
max(MyCount, key=int)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
max(map(int, MyCount))
```

Or if you want the return value to be the original string:

```
max(MyCount, key=int)
```

Comment: Calling `dict.keys` is here (and most places) unnecessary and potentially inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody ended up here looking for how to **sort by value** instead of the key:

```
max(MyCount, key=MyCount.get)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your keys are strings, they are compared lexicographically and '9' is the max value indeed.

What you are looking for is something like:`max(int(k) for k in MyCount)`

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
>>> u'10' > u'9'
False
```

Effectively, you're comparing the characters '1' and '9' here. What you want is probably this:

```
max(long(k) for k in MyCount)
```

or create the dictionary with numbers as keys (instead of strings).

Answer (score 1):

You use max for string values. You must convert them to int. Try something like:

```
print(max([int(s) for s in MyCount.keys()]))
```

Or as Tim suggested:

```
print(max(int(s) for s in MyCount))
```

Comment: You need neither the square brackets nor the `.keys()` method.