# Print Highest, Average, Lowest score of a file

Tags: python, max, average, type-conversion, min

I'm trying to print the highest, average, and lowest score of a file in python. But I keep getting error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10.
```

My *results.txt* file looks like this:

```
Johnny-8.65
Juan-9.12
Joseph-8.45
Stacey-7.81
Aideen-8.05
Zack-7.21
Aaron-8.31
```

And my code looks like this

```
func1={}
with open('results.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        name,value=line.split('-')
        value=float(value)
        if name in func1.keys():
           func1[name].append(value)
        else:
            func1[name]=[value]

#compute average: 
for name in func1:

    average=sum(func1[name])/len(func1[name])
    print("{} : {}".format(name,average))
```

Comment: Yeah, `8.65` is not an int. It's a float.

Comment: `8.65` is not an int

Comment: I changed line 5 to float instead of value and i'm getting this error.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Trent/Desktop/CreativeProgrammingChapter4.py", line 5, in <module>
    value=int(float)#or float
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'type'
>>>

Comment: Yeah, because `int(float)` tries to convert the `float` type object into an int.

Comment: No, they meant you should write `value=float(value)`...

Comment: Ah okay, sorry guys i'm a beginner and this is for college homework. So, I did value=float(value) which makes sense and it's printing the names and the values but it isn't printing the highest, average, and lowest.

Comment: Several users have edited your question to try to make it more clear. Please take a look and make sure the edits haven't broken the formatting of your original code. In python, indentation is very important. If it doesn't look like your original code, remember that formatting code blocks requires an indentation of 4 spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values that you provided in file are not `int` type.
For your approach you can use `float()`:

```
value = float(value)
```

If you need to extract integer:

```
s = "123"
num = int(s)
```

> num = 123

If you need to extract float number:

```
s = "123.12"
num = float(s)
```

> num = 123.12

You can refer to documentation: [Datatypes #1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datatypes.html)

Also there is nice post about converting number datatypes in python: [Parse String to Float or Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int)

How to get maximum key / value from dictionary refer to: [get max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary)[get max key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108042/get-max-key-in-dictionary)

Also, read this article. It will help you to ask clearer questions.
[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: So I changed it to         value=float() and it does print the names, but it's only printing 0.00 beside there name instead of actually printing the correct stuff?

Comment: No it hasn't, i've got it to print the numbers in the file but i'm having trouble getting it to print the highest and the lowest numbers as well as the average. How do I post my code in a comment so I can show you have i've got?

Comment: Alright i've edited my main question with the updated code that I have now.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone on this thread suggested you should change **int** to **float**. Regarding your comment above. You use

```
value=int(float) !
```

Float should be outside parentheses. Like this

```
value=float(value).
```

I run the code and it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you i've done this and it's printing the values now I just have to get it to print the highest, average, and lowest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scores={}
highest_score=0.0
highest=''
lowest_score=100.0
lowest=''
average=0.0
sums=0.0

files=open("results.txt","r").readlines()
for lines in files[0:]:
    line=lines.split("-")
    scores[line[0]]=line[1].strip()

for key,value in scores.items():
    if float(value)<lowest_score:
        lowest_score=float(value)
        lowest=key

    if float(value)>highest_score:
        highest_score=float(value)
        highest=key

    sums=sums+float(value)

print "highest score:",highest_score," of ",highest
print "lowest score:",lowest_score," of ",lowest
print "average: ",sums/len(scores)
```